# var keycode = window.event.keycode on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
var keycode = window.event.keycode;
game.keyDown(keycode);
```

This code works very well on Chrome, IE, Safari but when I try on Firefox, its getting error:

```
TypeError: window.event is undefined
```

Whats the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: `event = event || window.event;` You must have `event` as argument in handler.. `global event` is not available in all browsers!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 1):

`window.event` is aimed at older versions of IE.Also window.event doesn't exist in Firefox. That's because browser have different event models.

```
document.onmouseover = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
   document.getElementById("mouseX").innerHTML=event.clientX;
   document.getElementById("mouseY").innerHTML=event.clientY;

}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2kyzwet/)